# Inconsistency in printing SharePoint list items using jQuery REST

Tags: rest, jquery

I am retrieving data from my SharePoint site and printing it to a html table. The problem is that at times, when I print the data I fetched, my code fails to print all the data I expected. I have three items in task groups list. I expect them to be printed but the code prints either the three of them, a combination of two or just one. What could be the cause of this inconsistency? Please see my code below

```
//fetch task list, begin by getting the groups first
    $.ajax({
        url: serverURL + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Task Groups')/items?$Filter=Project eq "+PROJECT_ID,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var TaskGroups = data.d.results;
            var TasksHTML = '<h3>Project Task List</h3>';
            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<table class="table table-codensed table-hover table-bordered">';
            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<tr><th>#</th><th>Task</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></tr>';
            $.each(TaskGroups, function(groupID, group){
                //then get the individual tasks
                $.ajax({
                    url: serverURL + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project Tasks')/items?$Filter=Task_x0020_Group eq "+group.Id,
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<tr><td>'+(groupID+1)+'</td><td colspan="3">'+group.Title+'</td></tr>';
                        var Tasks = data.d.results;                            
                        $.each(Tasks, function(taskID, task){
                            //populate the Tasks
                            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<tr><td>'+(groupID+1)+'.'+taskID+1+'</td>';
                            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<td>'+task.Title+'</td>';
                            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<td>'+task.Start_x0020_Date+'</td>';
                            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<td>'+task.End_x0020_Date+'</td></tr>';
                            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<tr><td colspan="4"><a href="#" class="addtask" data-groupID="'+group.Id+'"></a></td></tr>';
                            /**
                            * jQuery is asynchronous, we thus have to test if this is the last record so that we can print
                            * we print if this is the last task in the last group or if this is the last group and it has no tasks
                            * @author Muya George mowyah@gmail.com
                            */
                            if (groupID == TaskGroups.length-1 && taskID == Tasks.length-1) {
                                TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<tr><td colspan="4"><a href="#" class="addgroup" data-projectid="'+PROJECT_ID+'">Add group</a></td></tr>';
                                TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'</table>';
                                $('#categories-content-pane').html(TasksHTML);
                            }
                        });
                        if (Tasks.length == 0) {
                             TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<tr><td colspan="4"><a href="#" class="addtask" data-groupID="'+group.Id+'">Add Tasks</a></td></tr>';
                        }
                        if (groupID == TaskGroups.length-1 && Tasks.length == 0) {
                            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<tr><td colspan="4"><a href="#" class="addgroup" data-projectid="'+PROJECT_ID+'">Add group</a></td></tr>';
                            TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'</table>';
                            $('#categories-content-pane').html(TasksHTML);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                    }
                });
            });
            if (TaskGroups.length == 0) {
                TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'<tr><td colspan="4"><a href="#" class="addgroup" data-projectid="'+PROJECT_ID+'">Add group</a></td></tr>';
                TasksHTML = TasksHTML+'</table>';
                $('#categories-content-pane').html(TasksHTML);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You realize you are using multiple asynchronous functions?

I believe that if you stop to perform asynchronous loops within other asynchronous loops, you will laugh solve your problem.

I suggest that every asynchronous loop you call a function passing the data to the same continuity to the process. Ride your table only after all finalized loops, so you will have a construction standard of your html and probably it will be consistent.

Example: Each loop "each" do not wait for the previous completion and you will have the data "mixing".

I hope helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I figured out how to go about it by replacing the second asynchronous call with a function call and using a callback to return the data.